# Handlebars return an array element with certain index if the length is unknown

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Using Handlebars and Node, I have an array with changing length and I need always to get the one before last element of it each time it changes.

So if you want to get the last element, you can do:

```
{{#each array}}
  {{#if @last}}
    {{this}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

and it will return you the last element.
I have Math helper, that can perform basic mathematical operations.
For example I can get with it the needed index number

```
{{math array.length '-' 1}}
```

but I cant use it with another block helper, for example:

```
{{#each array}}
  {{#if math @last '-' 1}}
    {{this}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

How could this be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register your own helper for that:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isSecondLastArrayItem', function(array, index, options) {

  if((array.length - 2) === index)
    return options.fn(this);

  return;

});
```

And use it like this:

```
{{#each array}}
  {{#isSecondLastArrayItem @root.array @index}}
    {{title}}
  {{/isSecondLastArrayItem}}
{{/each}}
```

Example data:

```
{ 
  array: [{ title: 'aa' }, { title: 'vv' }]
}
```

Try it out in the [sandbox](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/).

*EDIT: case for any index*

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isNthLastArrayItem', function(array, index, offset, options) {

  if(((array.length >= offset) && (array.length - offset) === index)
    return options.fn(this);

  return;

});
```

usage (for `2nd` item from the end):

```
{{#each array}}
  {{#isNthLastArrayItem @root.array @index 2}}
    {{title}}
  {{/isNthLastArrayItem}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves he particular problem, but in this case you nave to register special helper for every index you need. If there is more global solution for getting indexes with  `@first` and `@last` or `array.length` it would be great

Comment: I've edited my question; as far as I understand your question it is not possible to pass helpers result to another helper. I can only think of some ugly hacks using `eval()`, but still not sure if it'd even work.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you state that you cannot use your `math` helper within the mustaches of the `#if` block helper, like `{{#if math @last '-' 1}}`. This is not true. Handlebars supports [subexpressions](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions).

> Handlebars offers support for subexpressions, which allows you to invoke multiple helpers within a single mustache, and pass in the results of inner helper invocations as arguments to outer helpers. Subexpressions are delimited by parentheses.

However, `{{#if (math @last '-' 1)}}` will not make much sense because [`@last`](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#data-last) is a Boolean and I would advise against the oddity of subtracting `1` from `true` or `false`.

If your issue is to render a single element from your array - for example, the second to last - then I do not understand why you are `#each`ing through your `array`. All you need do is combine the built-in [`lookup` helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup) with your existing `math` helper and your template gets a whole lot simpler:

```
{{lookup array (math array.length '-' 2)}}
```

Note: Remember that JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed, so we need to subtract `2` to get the second from last element.

I have created a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/gpmzmtst/) for reference.